# Replication between two galera clusters

Tags: mysql, mariadb, clustering, galera

I currently have two 3 node mariadb (10.5.9) Galera clusters set up in different locations, I'm using standard replication to copy data between the primary and secondary.

What I've recently noticed is that while the slave node in the secondary location gets all of the data, it appears to be omitting things like the creation of new databases.

For example the slave node would have 100 db's while the other 2 nodes in the same galera cluster would have 85

Has anyone else experienced similar is there a setting or configuration i'm missing?

Comment: Check permissions.

Comment: If using [replication filtering](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-filters/), read the docs very carefully. database include/excludes aren't as obvious as the configuration options make them seem. Also are you using `log-slave-updates` on the Galera async master node to replication between Galera and its Async master. Are `server-ids` unique?

Comment: RickJames - permissioning doesn't appear to be an issue

@danblack - I'm not currently using replication filtering, server id's are unique and we do have log-slave-updates enabled.

Comment: Check if there are no replication filters set up that might be excluding certain databases from being replicated. Replication filters could be set up in your configuration file with settings like replicate-ignore-db or replicate-do-db.